# Why does this string mess with my python print statement

Tags: python, string

I came across this error when I was trying to print out some user defined strings. When I print out this string I get a weird interaction with the print statement and I am not sure what causes this. Can anyone help me on the right track? I'd be happy to post more information if it's needed!

In the following example the input "my_message" was used

Relevant code snippet:

```
print("APPENDING [[" + "test1" + "]]")
print("APPENDING [[" + message + "]]")
print(message)
```

Console output for snippet:

```
APPENDING [[test1]]
]]PENDING [[my_message
my_message
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's almost certainly a `'\r`' (carriage return) hiding out in the string. Try stripping the message:

```
print("APPENDING [[" + "test1" + "]]")
print("APPENDING [[" + message.strip() + "]]")
```

The carriage return will cause output to jump back to the beginning of the line, which is why you see the `]]` overwriting part of the line.

Comment: Perfect, that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasKruhlmann: are you using Python 3.2 by any chance?  There was a bug in 3.2.0 `input()` where on Windows the "\n" was stripped but not the preceding "\r".  That gave exactly these symptoms.

Comment: @cdarke I am not using the `input()` command I am getting the input from an IRC server and the format of the messages appears to be `message+\r\n`